# HR Department that keeps track of my profile updates on job portals?

Tags: human-resources

My company's HR department crawls leading job sites for profile updates from current employees.

Now I don't know if companies usually indulge in this sort of snooping but I am really shocked and frankly don't know how to react to this.

Please advise on how to go forward with this.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? As currently stated, your question is far too broad to receive anything but, "Yes companies do this," which you already know.

Comment: @kornerstoane "Please advise on how to go forward with this"

Comment: @Frisbee but what does that mean?  anonymoe, do you want to hide from HR, ask HR why they do this, change HR's policies, job-hunt without using the leading job sites, know how common this is, or what?  I'm putting the question on hold temporarily until the question is clarified; you can [edit] your question and that will send it to a review queue for possible reopening.

Comment: "I don't know if companies usually indulge in this sort of snooping" - If I check out my manager's public job profiles, is *that* "snooping"? Remember, public is public.

Comment: I tend to keep my linkedin profile up-to-date whether I'm looking for a new job or not.  But any of my resumes on monster, dice, etc. have got to be close to a decade old.  Most of the major job boards are useless, I've never landed a job using one.

Answer (score 3):

While I am surprised that they have the time and money to do that, it isn't surprising that some are doing this.

Companies are always interested in knowing if there will be either a mass exodus or a small exodus of key people. They conduct surveys of current employees to see where there are pockets of discontent.

I have seen sales pitches regarding tools that will scan the access records for the internal message board to see who is reading and posting negative or positive messages. They look for the types of messages that go viral. They can also look to identify which people are key to making changes, and which ones are thought leaders.

If they did track the number of changes to resumes, that could also be a sign that somebody was thinking of leaving.

I have heard for years that if a co-worker suddenly starts making tons of link requests they are either looking, or they have already found a job and want to make those last few link before walking out the door.

Remember HR works for management. Any information they can provide to management could save the company money.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Internet age.

You did the equivalent of buying a want-ad. You shouldn't be shocked or disappointed that HR reads the newspaper, especially when the point of the ad is to be visible to other companies' HR departments.

They probably weren't even looking for you, just investigating who might be available with skills similar to yours.

Anything you do on a public Internet site is just that, public. If there is anyone who shouldn't see it -- your boss, your spouse, your competitor, your customer, the authorities, ***anyone*** -- don't post it there, and preferably don't post it anywhere.

The good news is that, unless you were saying something you shouldn't have been, this isn't going to make much difference. If you *were* announcing that you were actively looking, or saying uncomplimentary things about your current employer, you really do have only yourself to blame.

Call it a learning experience, remember this for future reference, and move on.

Comment: And I down voted your question for changing the question from "My company's HR department crawls leading job sites for profile updates from current employees"  to "They probably weren't even looking for you".  Yes companies crawl for employees.

Comment: Some do. Some don't. My point is that claiming it's unfair or malicious is unreasonable if you actively put it where they can stumble across it. I don't feel like arguing exact degrees of probability;if it makes you feel better to downvote, feel free.

Comment: Probability?  The stated question is not about probability.  "My company's HR department crawls leading job sites for profile updates from current employees."

Comment: That's the assertion. It may be incorrect. I certainly don't know either way, and _it doesn't matter_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a reality and even used by Fortune 500 companies.

On a professional networking site like LinkedIn, make regular updates so that you don't flag a job hunt - your company will know you make regular updates and will be less likely to worry about them.

For job hunt sites either don't post or post and try and hide from search engines / crawlers.

For job hunt sites, search engines are used to find current employer or by your name or email.  Try to use a different name or email, or use tricks to disguise them (like spam does).  Don't list your current employer - state "please contact for current employer."  Don't use your actual title or the actual name of any project.  In general make it hard on the search engine.

On the other side if you want to send a warning message and you think you are underpaid and feel pretty confident you can find a better job, then post your resume as a warning message (like 30 days) before your next review.

Comment: *"post your resume as a warning message like 30 days before your review"* This advice would harm your relationship with your employer if you decide to stay (or worse, if nobody decides to hire you and you're stuck where you are). Don't play mind games with your employer - they're not mind readers. If you're not satisfied, tell them (unless you want to leave, in which case, just leave).

Comment: @kornerstoane You voted me down because you disagreed with that? Games? They are the one searching job sites for post.  How many times has a person had to get a new job offer before the company gave them a raise?

Comment: @kornerstoane Poorly written?  You can edit.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and grammar. If I changed any of your ideas, please feel free to edit them back. *I still disagree with your ideas to play games with your employer. And I also think it's bad advice to look for a job under a different/disguised name. As someone in a hiring position, I wouldn't trust someone who wasn't genuine.*

Comment: Posting a resume/profile on a job board is passive and ineffective anyway.  Peruse posted jobs at companies you'd like to work for and apply directly.

Comment: If you have to threaten to leave in order to get a raise, you may want to eave; they will not remember that kindly. Adversarial relationships with employers can be _very_ hard to repair. I grant that they're sometimes unavoidable, but.

Comment: @keshlam It was an example of A game.  Not a comment to do it or not.